# How to write fraction instead of decimal in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to write 4/3 as a fraction in C++. I know that 4/3 is equal to 1.33333.  But when I write 4/3 in the code it outputs it's quotient which is 1. Can anyobody tell me how to write this number as fraction?

The code:

```
double vol_sphere(double radiusS){
     return (4/3) * pi * pow(radiusS, 3);
}
```

Comment: What does 'instead of decimal' mean?

Comment: `4* pi * pow(radiusS, 3)/3` would solve the problem and should be slightly more accurate too

Answer (score 1):

Because 4 and 3 are both integers, when you perform division of two integers, the result will be also integer, so 1.333333333 will be only 1.